Firestore Security Rules: How to Securely Allow Users to Access Members Based on Group Assignment?
I'm working on a Firebase Firestore project where I have three collections: users, groups, and members. Each user can belong to one or more groups, and each member belongs to a specific group. I want to set up Firestore security rules to ensure that:
Admin users can read and write all documents.
Non-admin users can only read and write their own records or records from groups they belong to.
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Users Collection Rules
    match /users/{userId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

    // Groups Collection Rules
    match /groups/{groupId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && 
                        get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "admin";
    }

    // Members Collection Rules
    match /members/{memberId} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null && (
          // Allow admin users
          get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.role == "admin" ||
          
          // Allow users accessing their own record
          request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId ||
          
          // Allow users who belong to a group that the member belongs to
          get(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(resource.data.group)).data.assignedUsers.has(request.auth.uid)
      );
    }
  }
}

Example objects
User Object (users collection):
{
  "email": "user@example.com",
  "role": "user",
  "assignedGroups": [
    {
      "groupId": "groupId1",
      "groupName": "Group1"
    },
    {
      "groupId": "groupId2",
      "groupName": "Group2"
    }
  ]
}

Group Object (groups collection):
{
  "name": "Group1",
  "assignedUsers": [
    "userId1",
    "userId2"
  ]
}

Member Object (members collection):
{
  "group": "Group1",
  "userId": "userId1",
  "name": "John"
}

Function to fetch members from firestore:
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMembers = async () => {
        try {
            const user = auth.currentUser;
            if (!user) {
                console.error("User not authenticated");
                return;
            }

            console.log("Authenticated user:", user);

            const userDoc = await getDoc(doc(db, 'users', user.uid));
            if (!userDoc.exists()) {
                console.error("User document does not exist");
                return;
            }

            const userData = userDoc.data();
            console.log("User data:", userData);
            
            const userRole = userData.role;

            if (userRole === 'admin') {
                const membersSnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, 'members'));
                const membersData = membersSnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
                console.log('Fetched members (admin):', membersData);
                setMembers(membersData);
                setFilteredMembers(membersData);
            } else {
                const assignedGroupNames = userData.assignedGroups.map(group => group.groupName);
                console.log("Assigned groups:", assignedGroupNames);

                if (assignedGroupNames.length > 0) {
                    const membersCollection = collection(db, 'members');
                    const q = query(membersCollection, where('group', 'in', assignedGroupNames));
                    const membersSnapshot = await getDocs(q);
                    const membersData = membersSnapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() }));
                    console.log('Fetched members (user):', membersData);
                    setMembers(membersData);
                    setFilteredMembers(membersData);
                } else {
                    console.log('No assigned groups found');
                    setMembers([]);
                    setFilteredMembers([]);
                }
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching members:", error);
        }
    };
    fetchMembers();
}, []);

When I try to apply these rules, I'm running into issues where non-admin users are unable to fetch members that belong to their assigned groups. In my console i get error about "Missing or insufficient permissions", so i would assume there is something wrong with my security rules.
Is my approach for checking membership in a group via security rules correct?
How can I correctly reference fields within the Firestore security rules to enforce these permissions?
Are there any best practices for organizing rules or structuring data to achieve this kind of group-based access control?
I would appreciate any guidance or examples from anyone who has implemented something similar.
I implemented Firestore security rules to restrict access to certain collections based on user roles and group memberships. Specifically, I attempted to allow users to access member records if they belong to a group associated with that member. The goal was to ensure that only admins have full access, while regular users can only access members within their assigned groups.
I expected the rules to work such that when a regular user queries the members collection, they only receive documents where the group field matches the groupName of any group in their assignedGroups array. However, I encountered persistent errors during rule validation and issues with the permissions not behaving as expected.
I'm looking for guidance on how to correctly structure these rules or whether there is a different approach I should consider for achieving this level of access control.
